# Data table, showing change from last period where value was 0

Tags: data-tables

In a data table, we are showing current period value and also we show the change in percentage compared to the last period. In cases, where the last period value was 0, we can't calculate the percentage from nothing to something. The correct way would be to show the infinity symbol, but I can't to that neither, cause psychologically it won't be good and users won't understand that. 
So I have come so far that I need to show something like that: "last period was 0, so there would not be any percentage".

Any ideas how to show that? It feels to me that showing symbol >0 is hard to understand.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Try being explicit about why there's no percentage and provide a hover tip...

Give them a detail on demand, either through a hover state, or even provide a <kbd>?</kbd> so they can see it.

[image]

You can do this unobtrusively, so users who use the application frequently are not hindered, but those who need an explanation can easily get one.

You can try several different representations, such as 'n/a', or 'none'. Test which one seems clearest